# Accessing private file from local storage (laravel) by Axios call in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, single-page-application

I am building and SPA using Vue.js and Laravel. My problem is that i am unable to fetch image that is stored in Local storage that **must be private**. This file is under /Storage/app/private/privateImage.png

Of course I am able to use public files by using storage link but this is not an option in this case as long as files in private directory are private and should be shown only after certain validation etc.

This is my controller method which returns file:

```
public function loadPrivateFile()
{
    $file_path = "/private/image2.png";

    if (!Storage::disk('local')->exists($file_path)) {
        return "doesnt exists";
    } else {
        // return "exists";
        $local_path = config('filesystems.disks.local.root') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_path;
        return response()->file($local_path);
    }
}
```

After calling this method via Axios I can even see the image as response in browser developer tools however i am unable to bind to and img tag. When i was building non SPA pages without vue I used route function inside of src in image and that worked, however now I am in Vue and I cannot access it.

I have searched the forum and all the posts relate to public storage which is not a solution in my case. Is there some way how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could encode the image as base64 string on the server side and just bind it to :src attribute in vue or transfer it normally and encode it to base64 on the client side

Look at [this issue on the axios github](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/513) page

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, I actually achieved solution by simply calling the url of my controller where i have this methods insisde of my src tag like this :src="/fetch/privateimage/image.jpg"

Comment: @EUCDev are you fetching the image through API or WEB route? That's an interesting solution.